# React native styled components cannot override component's style

Tags: javascript, react-native, styled-components

I have a weird problem with stlyed components. I have a component Header with a basic style but when a try to use this component and extend the style nothing happens. Can someone tell me what going on?

```js
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
export const Container = styled.SafeAreaView``;

export const Content = styled.View`
  height: 72px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
`;
```

```js
Header component

import React, { PropsWithChildren, FC } from 'react';
import { Container, Content } from './styles';

const Header: FC = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<unknown>, props) => {
  return (
    <Container {...props}>
      <Content>{children}</Content>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

```js
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

import Header from '../components/Header/index';

export const Container = styled(Header)`
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
`;
```

Comment: You have to add in your header component a property ```className?: string```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your props from into your `Header` component. In `Container` or `Content`. It's won't be done instead of you.

Your `Header` is a React component and he "doesn't know what to do" with props that it will receive from `Container` - `const Container = styled(Header)'...'`.
Props will be recognized correctly if component is working with styles, as `Text`, `View`, ...

```js
export const Container = styled(Header)`
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
`;

const Header: FC = ({ children, ...restProps }: PropsWithChildren<unknown>) => {
  return (
    <Container {...restProps}>
      <Content>{children}</Content> // or <Content {...restProps}>...
    </Container>
  );
};
```

or you have 2 next options, without passing the props - just editing your inner Container. It's depends on your codestyle of the project

```html
const Header: FC = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<unknown>) => {
  return (
    <Container background="blue" height="200px">
      <Content>{children}</Content>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

```html
export const NewContainer = styled(Container)`
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
`;

const Header: FC = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren<unknown>) => {
  return (
    <NewContainer>
      <Content>{children}</Content>
    </NewContainer>
  );
};
```